# With C++-17, how to populate a tuple from a vector of string

Tags: c++, c++17

With C++-17, is there an idiomatic way to transform a std::vector into a std::tuple provided there are reasonable transformations from std::string to each Arg type in the Args... list.

Consider this broken code as a way to describe the idea.

```
template<class T> T transform_arg(std::string const &s);
template<> double transform_arg(std::string const &s) { return atof(s.c_str());}
template<> int transform_arg(std::string const &s) { return atoi(s.c_str());}

template<typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> create_tuple(std::vector<std::string> arguments) {
  return std::make_tuple<Args...>(transform_arg<Args>(arguments.pop_back()), ...));
}
```

Suppose we then invoke it this way.

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
args.push_back("3.14");
args.push_back("2");
args.push_back("1.0");
create_tuple<double,int,double>(args);
```

This would generate a tuple as double, int, double with those values populated inside the tuple by way of the conversion functions.

Comment: I do not think that's possible as `std::vector` has a **dynamic** size whereas `std::tuple` needs some **static** (id compile-time) information.

Comment: Let's assume that the number of elements in the vector is the same as the number of arguments in the variadic list Args. So sizeof...(Args)==arguments.size().

Comment: You can do that *if* you provide the types in `...Args` at compile-time. Otherwise there's no way to deduce them, so you'd need type erasure.

Comment: To be more clear, yes, ...Args would be known at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to map the value of a `std::string` input to multiple types, as the value is only known at *run-time*.

The best you can do is create a tuple out of the vector, provided you know its size at compile-time:

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
auto create_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const std::vector<std::string>& arguments) {
    return std::make_tuple(arguments[Is]...);
}

template <std::size_t N>
auto create_tuple(const std::vector<std::string>& arguments) {
    return create_tuple_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, arguments);
}
```

Usage:

```
const std::vector<std::string> inputs{"100", "42.22"};
const auto t = create_tuple<2>(inputs);
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/edUhHM)

---

**EDIT:** if you want to select the types manually:

```
template<class T> T transform_arg(std::string const &s);
template<> double transform_arg(std::string const &s) { return atof(s.c_str());}
template<> int transform_arg(std::string const &s) { return atoi(s.c_str());}

template <typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
auto create_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const std::vector<std::string>& arguments) {
    return std::make_tuple(transform_arg<Args>(arguments[Is])...);
}

template <typename... Args>
auto create_tuple(const std::vector<std::string>& arguments) {
    return create_tuple_impl<Args...>(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}, arguments);
}
```

Usage:

```
const std::vector<std::string> inputs{"100", "42.22", "11"};
const auto t = create_tuple<int, double, int>(inputs);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), const std::tuple<int, double, int>>);
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z77P2j)

Comment: I keep thinking that there is a way up this hill perhaps via std::tuple_cat and some variadic template work that builds it up recursively.

Comment: @EricJohnson: you can't achieve your original goal. You cannot select an overload or another depending on the run-time value of a string.

Comment: My wording of my question is unclear. My intent is not to select the overload depending upon the run time value of the string. The run time value of the string is the input to the specific conversion function. The specific conversion function should be selected by the compile time specified type at the specific place in the Args list. I will add a bit more to my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @EricJohnson: oh I see now. Updating my answer.